# Pandas equivalent of isnull for column modification statements

Tags: python, pandas, isnull

I'm executing the following code

```
Q = pd.DataFrame([['a',1], ['b',2]], columns=['x','y']) 
W = pd.DataFrame([['a',1], ['c',8]], columns=['x', 'y'])

Q.set_index(['x'], inplace=True)
W.set_index(['x'], inplace=True)

Q.y = Q.y + W.y
display(mydata)
```

and receive table

```
    y
x   
a   3.0
b   NaN
```

There is no corresponding line for 'b' in table W and therefore pandas makes (2+NaN) which results in NaN.
Is any equivalent of isnull available in pandas in order to replace NaN with zero and get

```
    y
x   
a   3.0
b   2.0
```

?

I understand, that it is possible with merge, fill_nan. But I'm looking for a way without merge.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
Q.y = Q.y.add( W.y, fill_value=0)
print (Q)
     y
x     
a  2.0
b  2.0
```

Comment: Great thanks. And what if I need to make weight1*Q.y + weigth2*W.y? Actually with syntax you have shown, I can make it like weight1 * Q.y.add(weigth2/weigth1 * W.y, fill_value=0). Is it a better way?